# how to make multi modal ( with pure css) to target unique id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multi galleries with different gallery sets but the problem is how to target  with existing code right one on event

Here is my current js that work on single modal

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}
```

here is html code that open via ID;  what i need is to have like data-target="model-01" and then model-02  to know what need to be open

````html
 <a id="myBtn" href="javascript:void();">
 <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <?php
                    include_once("gallery/gallery_modal.php");
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>```
````

Comment: This answer will not help me if i just change id with class

Comment: The problem start when i put php foreach loop on` <a id="myBtn" href="javascript:void();">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add same class "open-modal" and unique data-target attribute to all buttons

```
<a id="myBtn" class="open-modal" data-target="myModal<?=$r['id'];?>" href="#">Button</a>

<span class="close" data-target="myModal<?=$r['id'];?>">&times;</span>
```

Than in js

```
$('.open-modal').on('click', function(){
   event.preventDefault();
   var modal = $('#' + $(this).data('target'));

   modal.css('display', 'block');
});

$('.close').on('click', function(){
   var modal = $('#' + $(this).data('target'));

   modal.css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Thank you but this solution will not work for me  i have five different template in modal  and every button need to target right modal this why i need to add id of the gallery

Comment: I edited answer to show how you can use this approach to create 5 buttons with 5 modals

Comment: the problem is that  button is in different file then  modal  i need to do  with js or jquery

Comment: i need to get id via  data-target-id="m-<?=$r['id'];?>"   or   id="myModal-<?=$r['id'];?>"

Comment: What about modal id    <div id="myModal" class="modal">   ?

Comment: you cahnge modal id to same value as data-target - "myModal<?=$r['id'];?>"

Comment: i'm getting this error  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: this error is because href="javascript:void();". Replace it to "#" and add prevent default to open-modal function. Also do not forget add data-target attribute to the close span also. I have edited comment once again